# how do i update time in my program?

Tags: pygame

i am totally new to python. thus please explain thoroughly wen u respond to my query.

in my code i want to measure the time the player lasts before his cursor touches the bouncing ball on the screen but the time i am obtaining is the sum of all the seconds since the first time the command was initialised. i need to stop the counting of seconds as soon as the user ends the game and to begin afresh wen the play again option is chosen...

also i wud lyk a way to make the player qualify for the next level without usin d detection of position of mouse....since dat is making the program code logic incorrect...

```
    here is my code:


    import pygame,sys
    from pygame.locals import*
    from pygame import *
    import random
    def main():
# set up sounds
# import pygame
#gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
#pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')
#from pygame import *
#import random




#pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

#background =image.load('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oearth.png')



        ballpic = image.load('ball1.png')
        ballpic.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

        #find a way to include verification of more than one colour key
        # to add more than one shape....pending

        numballs = 10
        delay = 5

        done = False

        balls = []
        stars = []
#generate an if loop for execution of both the parts
        k = 2

        init()
        screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
        display.set_caption('mouse game by shivangi and ananya')
        event.set_grab(1)




#pygame.time.Clock() Creates a Clock object (assign this to a name), which you can then call the tick() method on
#to find out how much time has passed since the last time you called tick()
#pygame.time.delay(milliseconds) Pauses game for time specified
#pygame.time.get_ticks() Returns the number of milliseconds passed since pygame.init() was #called






        for count in range(numballs):
            balls.append(dict)
            balls[count] = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'xmove': random.randint(1, 2), 'ymove': random.randint(1, 2)}

        screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))    #####screen = display.set_mode((640,480),FULLSCREEN,32).....check functioning...



#pygame.display.list_modes()
#[(800, 600), (1280, 1024), (1280, 960), (1280, 800), (1280, 768), (1280, 720),
#(1152, 864), (1088, 612), (1024, 768), (960, 600), (848, 480), (800, 600),
#(720, 576), (720, 480), (640, 480), (640, 400), (512, 384), (480, 360), (400, 300),
#(320, 240), (320, 200), (640, 480)]




        while done == False:
            pygame.time.Clock()
            init()
            screen.fill((0,100,0))

            for count in range(numballs):
                screen.blit(ballpic, (balls[count]['x'], balls[count]['y']))

            display.update()
            time.delay(delay)

            for count in range(numballs):
                balls[count]['x'] = balls[count]['x'] + balls[count]['xmove']
                balls[count]['y'] = balls[count]['y'] + balls[count]['ymove']

            for count in range(numballs):
                if balls[count]['x'] > 620:
                    balls[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(-2, 0)
                if balls[count]['x'] < -10:
                    balls[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(0, 6)
                if balls[count]['y'] > 470:
                    balls[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(-9, 0)
                if balls[count]['y'] < -10:
                    balls[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(0, 5)

            for e in event.get():
                if e.type == KEYUP:
                    if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        done = True

            if screen.get_at((mouse.get_pos())) == (227,209,43):
                done = True

            if done == True:
                    #pygame.mixer.init()
                    break
        sec = time.get_ticks()/1000
        quit()


        while sec < k:
             print "you lasted for only",sec,"seconds...try again to qualify for the next level..."
             quit()
             break
        time_lasted = 0



        while sec >= k:
             starpic = image.load('star.png')
             starpic.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
             #find a way to include verification of more than one colour key...PENDING

             numstars = 30
             delay = 8

             done = False

             stars = []
             for count in range(numstars):
                     stars.append(dict)
                     stars[count] = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'xmove': random.randint(1, 2), 'ymove': random.randint(1, 2)}


             screen = display.set_mode((640, 480))
             display.set_caption('mouse game')
             event.set_grab(1)

             while done == False:
                 init()
                 screen.fill((160,32,240))

                 for count in range(numstars):
                     screen.blit(starpic, (stars[count]['x'], stars[count]['y']))

                 display.update()
                 time.delay(delay)

                 for count in range(numstars):
                     stars[count]['x'] = stars[count]['x'] + stars[count]['xmove']
                     stars[count]['y'] = stars[count]['y'] + stars[count]['ymove']

                 for count in range(numstars):
                     if stars[count]['x'] > 620:
                         stars[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(-2, 0)
                     if stars[count]['x'] < -10:
                         stars[count]['xmove'] = random.randint(0, 2)
                     if stars[count]['y'] > 470:
                         stars[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(-2, 0)
                     if stars[count]['y'] < -10:
                         stars[count]['ymove'] = random.randint(0, 2)

                 for e in event.get():
                     if e.type == KEYUP:
                         if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                             done = True 

                 if screen.get_at((mouse.get_pos())) == (255,255,255,255):
                         done = True
                         if done == True:
                                 time_lasted = time.get_ticks()/1000
                                 quit()
                                 break

             #sec = time.update()
             #time_lasted = time.update()

             #correction of time error to be done....pending....

             quit()
             print "You lasted for", sec, "seconds in the first level!"
             print "\n"
             print "you lasted for",time_lasted,"in the second level!"
             print "\n"
             print "your total score is :", int(sec) + int(time_lasted)
             print "\n"
             print "game over...! Thank you for playing!! :D :P :)"
             quit()
             break



    main()
    x = 1
    x = raw_input("Do you want to play again?")

    while x.upper() in  ['YES','Y']:
        main()
        x =  raw_input("Do you want to play again?")

    while x.upper() in  ['NO','N']:
        break
```

Comment: Format your code and remove unused lines ! Nobody will read it.

Comment: Fix your spelling mistakes, it's a pain to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# when player starts game
start = time.get_ticks()

# during game 
current = time.get_ticks()

time_you_played = (current - start)/1000
```

---

EDIT:

Timer to count seconds.

```
class Timer():

    def __init__(self):
        self._start = 0

    def start(self):
        self._start = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def current(self):
        return (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self._start)/1000
```

Example - how to use:

```
import pygame

# add class Timer here 

pygame.init()

t = Timer()

t.start() # start or restart timer

pygame.time.wait(3000) # for test only

print t.current() # print seconds

pygame.time.wait(2000) # for test only

print t.current() # print seconds
```

You don't have to stop timer because you can use `start()` to restart timer.

Comment: thnx a lot... i wud also appreciate if sum alternate logic cud be proposed for the qualification of the player instead of collision detection since dat makes the code logic incorrect

Comment: and is there no function for initialising and deactivating the time.get() command dat can be used rather than subtracting the time as suggested...

Comment: People need `time` to controll many things at the same time (and they use similar method as in example) so they don't want to deactivate it. But you can using my example to create own timer class with deactivation.